# Cannot play audio from assets "it is probably compressed"

Tags: android, audio

Hi I am writing an android app that will play a set of audio files that I deliver with the app as well as allow users to create and play their own audio.  The problem I have is that I don't know where to store the files.  If I store them in the external (sdcard) location, I am not sure how I will send those files to the user's external storage when they install my app. I thought I could some in the assets and the custom sounds externally.

when I try to do this however I get the following error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed

here is my code:

```
try {
                Constants.mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getApplicationContext().getAssets().openFd("songid.mus");
                Constants.mPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
                Constants.mPlayer.prepare();
                Constants.mPlayer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("", "prepare() failed", e);
            }
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks!
Radha

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix you could [avoid compression](http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-android-apps/) by changing the name of your file to `songid.mp3`.

The author of that post also suggests passing an extension with the `-0` option to `aapt` on the command line:

> First, you can give your asset file an
>   extension in the list above. While
>   this does not necessarily make sense,
>   it can be an easy workaround if you
>   don’t want to deal with aapt on the
>   command line. The other option is to
>   pass a specific extension to the -0
>   flag, such as -0 db, to disable
>   compression for assets with that
>   extension. You can pass the -0 flag
>   multiple times, and each time with a
>   separate extension, if you need more
>   than one type to be uncompressed.

If you're feeling adventurous you could try to replace `aapt` with a script that calls `aapt` with `-0 mus` as in [this post](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2010/10/09/disable-asset-compression-with-android-aapt/).

Comment: Thanks Matthew!  I changed the name from songid.mus to songid.3gp.  That fixed my first exception. Much appreciated.  I did get another exception after this point that I want to describe for anyone who makes the same mistake as me.  :-)  I got a "java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1"  It took me a while to figure out that I needed to add a start and duration:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matthew!  I changed the name from songid.mus to songid.3gp.  That fixed my first exception. Much appreciated.

I did get another exception after this point that I want to describe for anyone who makes the same mistake as me.  :-)  I got a `java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1`

It took me a while to figure out that I needed to add a start and duration as well:

```
Constants.mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getApplicationContext().getAssets().openFd("songid.3gpp");
long start = afd.getStartOffset();
long end = afd.getLength();
Constants.mPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), start,end);
Constants.mPlayer.prepare();
Constants.mPlayer.start();
```

It works!  Thanks!